# TextView scrollable in landscape but shown in full height in portrait orientation

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I want my TextView to be scrollable in landscape but shown in full height in portrait orientation. 
If I change the height of TextView I will get the scrollbar but I will get it in both landscape and portrait orientations, see screenshot:
[image]

In portrait there is enough space to stretch the TextView to the full height.

But if I stretch the TextView in portrait orientation to its full height (that the whole content is shown) the text will be overlaping other elements (see Situation 2) in landscape orientation or if I move it, it will be out of sight and there will not be any scrollbar that makes the text scrollable (see Situation 3).

[image]

[image]

What I want achive is that TextView in landscape orientation is like in Situation 1 (with scroll) and in portrait orientation like in Situation 2 (full content).

Is it possible to achive it without using java code? Or should I use if/else statemants?

Comment: make different xml files for both landscape and portrait mode

Answer (score 0):

First try to get the screen orientation and then based on the current Orientation, show or hide the textview scrollbar

```
int orientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    // code for portrait mode
    textview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false); 
} else {
    // code for landscape mode
    textview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
}
```

Also add this to your activity, if you are using only one Layout for your activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with XML by creating two layout resource folders-- one for portrait and the other for landscape.
Then wrap up your XML with ScrollView as below;

```
<ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

All the layouts encompassed by the above ScrollView will have the ability to scroll on different screen sizes if the screen cannot contain all the views at once.
Note: the XML you define inside this ScrollView is your really design, the ScrollView only makes the layouts and views scrollable.
For more information on supporting different screen sizes, you can refer to https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes